# Displacement of an object after period of time when velocity is trigonometric function of displacement

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

I'm trying to find a formula representing the angular displacement of an object fixed on a circle (as in, it cannot move any closer or further away) with a constant linear velocity. (Essentially any motion perpendicular to the circle is completely ignored).

Here's a diagram of the situation as I understand it.
[image]

I know that the perpendicular motion component of a linear force is equal to the sine of the difference between it's relative angle and the angle of the point on the circle on which it's applied, which lets me work out the angular velocity at any given point.

What I want to do is take that knowledge and derive a formula that will allow me to work out the angular position of the object after a given time interval. My knowledge of calculus is fairly rusty and my attempts to use this function as the ds/dt and then integrate from their back up to a more usable form have proven to be less than accurate.

If I take this information and produce an iterative graph of the angular velocity and displacement over time, I get graphs that look like (given that the angle of the linear motion is $\frac{\pi}{4}$).

[image]

Comment: I see a lot of concepts here that are either unclear, or used incorrectly. What is "linear motion" (the blue in the picture)? Is the circle itself actually moving? What is "component of a linear force"? You haven't said anything about force until that moment. What do you understand by "angular displacement" (to me, this is the angle A in your picture)? What is this "relative angular velocity" (also in the picture) and what is it relative to? Actually, this last question applies to any use of the word "relative" in your post.

Comment: i'm not very good at explaining myself in mathematical terms (I'm a programmer who hasn't formally studied maths for years now) so I apologise if I'm unclear.

Perhaps a better way of explaining the problem is to think of it as being a linear motion problem.

I have an object moving in a straight line. It's velocity at any point is equal to sin(k - s) where |k - s| < pi and k is a fixed constant. How can I turn that information into a formula that expresses s in terms of t?

(I guess the actual question is how can I integrate sin(k - s) with regards to t - as velocity is ds/dt)

Comment: You can't integrate it with respect to $t$, rather you need to solve a differential equation. Are you interested in how it's done, or just the result? If the latter, you can always try WolframAlpha for things like that: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=s%27(t)+%3D+sin(k-s(t))